# How to compare same file with other branch file saved with different name

Tags: git, android-studio

Was named: `UsrActivity.java` now named: `ProfileActivity` git diff doesn't show it's side by side diff window view of Android Studio, instead it shows single current class file.

How to compare `ProfileActivity.java` of 'OldBranch' with `UsrActivity.java` of 'DevBranch'

In short, How to compare two independent files across the branch. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Updated** with information supplied by torek; not sure why he didn't post this as an answer, because it's a much shorter path than what I'd outlined; so rather than leave it in comments, here it is:

`git diff` can work on identifiers for two `BLOB`s, and a shorthand for identifying a `BLOB` is `<commit>:<path>`.  so

```
git diff master:UsrActivity.java branch:ProfileActivity.java
```

(adjusted as necessary for paths and commit identification).

---

**Original Response**

You can give two commits, but then only one path.  You can give two paths, but then you can't specify commits.  If there's a way to specify two commits and a different path for each, I don't know it... So I think to do what you want takes a little extra work.

One way is by getting the object ID (SHA) for each file.  For a checked-out file, you could say

```
git hash-object UsrActivity.java
```

To get the has of an object that isn't checked out, you could do something like

```
git log -n1 -raw --no-abbrev <commit-or-branch-containing-file> -- ProfileActivity.java
```

(There are probably simpler versions of that; I haven't had much caffeine yet this morning.)  Or of course you can check out a commit that has the 2nd file (or just check that file out from such a commit) and go back to the `git hash-object` command.

Once you have a hash for each file, you'd just say

```
git diff <file-1-hash> <file-2-hash>
```

Of course, if you end up checking both files out into the worktree, then you can just diff them directly

```
git diff UsrActivity.java ProfileActivity.java
```

Comment: Use `git rev-parse` to turn any arbitrary commit-specifier-plus-path-name into the committed file's blob hash: `git rev-parse OldBranch:ProfileActivity.java` for instance. Then, since `git diff <hash1> <hash2>` works, so does `git diff <rev1>:<path1> <rev2>:<path2>`.